# Amber force field parameters

Tags: molecular-dynamics

I have a few specific questions on Amber force field parameters. I spent some time looking for answers on the web and this answered some but not all of them.

The `ffbonded.itp` file provides parameters for bonded interactions and I don't understand what are the units of some of the parameters:

1) in `[ angletypes ]` section - what is the unit of `cth` parameter (`292.880` in the example below)

```
H0  CT  H0           1   109.500    292.880 ; 03GLY
```

2) in `[ dihedraltypes ]` section - what is the unit of `kd` parameter (`4.60240` in the example below)

```
CA  CA  CA  OH       4      180.00     4.60240     2    ;
```

3) also in  `[ dihedraltypes ]` section - there is a `func` column, which takes values either 4 or 9. Where can I find these formulas?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about using a specific software, not physics.